The Theatre Ticket
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {Quantity};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,10) node[above] {Price};
\draw (2,8) -- (8,2) node[midway,below] {Demand Curve};
\draw (1,9) -- (9,1) node[midway,above] {Social Value Curve};
\draw[dashed] (4,4) -- (0,4) node[left] {$5};
\draw[dashed] (4,4) -- (4,0) node[below] {Q^*};
\draw[dashed] (6,6) -- (0,6) node[left] {$6};
\draw[dashed] (6,6) -- (6,0) node[below] {Q^E};
\end{tikzpicture}

Welcome to tex.sx.  What is your question?  You can format code by highlighting it with your mouse, then clicking on the {} icon above the question box.

Note that you need $...$ to write things in math mode if you want to use operators such as ^. You probably want to replace {Q^*} by {$Q^*$} and {Q^E} by {$Q^E$}. As the dollar sign has a special meaning in TeX, you need to escape it if you want to typeset it: replace {$5} by {\$5} and {$6} by {\$6}.

Please don't use random tags. How is the question related to [tag:ConTeXt] or [tag:equations]? Two of the tags are even without any description and therefore more or less unspecified.

You probably want something like this (although I am unsure about the positioning of the Demand Curve and the Social Value Curve):
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8] 
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {Quantity}; 
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,10) node[above] {Price};

\draw (2,8) -- (8,2) node[midway,below] {Demand Curve}; 
\draw (1,9) -- (9,1) node[midway,above] {Social Value Curve};

\draw[dashed] (4,4) -- (0,4) node[left] {\$5}; 
\draw[dashed] (4,4) -- (4,0) node[below] {$Q^*$};

\draw[dashed] (6,6) -- (0,6) node[left] {\$6}; 
\draw[dashed] (6,6) -- (6,0) node[below] {$Q^E$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The dollar sign ($) has a special meaning in TeX. If you want to typeset it, you need to escape it using \$. It's meaning is to enter math mode which you need if you want to use operators such as ^ for superscript numbers or letters.

@October Note also that Jasper included three lines of code before your code, and one line after.  That allows us to copy and paste the code and immediately compile to get the picture.
